# Choose which OS to boot on loadup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, bios

I have Ubuntu 16.10 installed on my hard drive and Windows 8.1 on my USB. When it is plugged in, I normally go to BIOS each time to edit startup order in order to load the one I want.

Is there a way to use GRUB to choose between OS's on my USB and Ubuntu? (I already made it so GRUB always loads on startup.)

I have looked at other questions and none worked.

Comment: grub should choose to boot either os. is windows not on the list?

Comment: No, I'll try again though. Restarting

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Nope, it doesn't show. But if I change BIOS boot priority to have external drives higher than internal drives then it just loads up Windows without GRUB.

Comment: Do you have a grub menu with multiple ubuntu enteries ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time If not, hold shift, If so we need to add windows.

Comment: On my GRUB menu I have: Ubuntu, Ubuntu Advanced, Memtest (something), and another Memtest (something). By something I mean I forgot what it said there. So 2 Ubuntu and 2 Memtest.

Comment: I think what you want is "chain loading"  https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Chain_002dloading.html

Comment: Ok, I honestly don't understand that page but it seems as it may be helpful. Can you post an explanation as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I found out my answer. With the USB plugged in type in the command line:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Along with the normal Ubuntu and Memtest it said:

```
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sdb1
```